# How to format the text inside the StyledText widget

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I am trying to read a file and display it in a styled widget. But when i display the output in console, It comes with the indentation and line breaks but when I try to display it in the widget the out output comes continuously.

Expected output:

```
 void add(int x,int y){
    int z=x+y;
    System.out.println("The added value is:"+z);
  }
```

Actual output inside styledText:

```
void add(int x,int y){int z=x+y; System.out.println("The added value is:"+z); }
```

I have tried googling ,But i have not found the solution yet. Please give me suggestions.

Updated:

```
  StyledText editor = new StyledText(viewparent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP |SWT.V_SCROLL);
  BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String str;                          
  System.out.println("File contents :");

        while ((str = buff.readLine()) != null) {
           Text.append(str);
           System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Comment: If I understand right you are trying to create a program like notepad++ that displays and formats the code??

Comment: You need to show us your code

Comment: What does this have to do with Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readLine` method of `BufferedReader` does not include the line endings in the text it returns. So you need to add a new line when you add the text to `StyledText`:

```
editor.append(str);
editor.append('\n');
```